# HTML Divs and Suggestions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently got help on my content slider, and I want to change the images to divs so that I can put information etc in there.

I know it may not be super complicated but I don't want to screw everything else, and I want to do it the right way. I also am asking on any suggestions to do with the black around the border of the page. I want it to have a clean look, but the black definitely doesn't do that for it.

```js
// just querying the DOM...like a boss!
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

// the activeLink provides a pointer to the currently displayed item
var activeLink = 0;

// setup the event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);

    // identify the item for the activeLink
    link.itemID = i;
}

// set first item as active
links[activeLink].classList.add("active");

function setClickedItem(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();

    var clickedLink = e.target;
    activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;

    changePosition(clickedLink);
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}

// Handle changing the slider position as well as ensure
// the correct link is highlighted as being active
function changePosition(link) {
    link.classList.add("active");

    var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");
    wrapper.style.left = position;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 5000px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    transition: left .5s ease-in-out;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 600px;
    white-space: normal;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#itemOne {
    background-color: #ADFF2F;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/blueSquare.png");
}
#itemTwo {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/yellowSquare.png");
}
#itemThree {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/pinkSquare.png");
}
#itemFour {
    background-color: #DC143C;
    background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/graySquare.png");
}
#contentContainer {
    width: 1250px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
#navLinks {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid white;
}
#navLinks ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
#navLinks ul li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 90px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border: white 5px solid;
}
#navLinks ul li:hover {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#navLinks ul li.active {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline-width: 7px;
}
#navLinks ul li.active:hover {
    background-color: #484848;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#navLinks ul li.active {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline-width: 7px;
}
#navLinks ul li.active:hover {
    background-color: #484848;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#b1 {
    background-image: url(100x100.gif);
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itemOne" class="content"></div>
        <div id="itemTwo" class="content"></div>
        <div id="itemThree" class="content"></div>
        <div id="itemFour" class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navLinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b1" data-pos="0px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b2" data-pos="-1250px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b3" data-pos="-2500px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b4" data-pos="-3750px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b5" data-pos="-5000px"></li>
        <li class="itemLinks" id="b6" data-pos="-6250px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: remove from #contentContainer the border properties if you want no border and provide a clearer question

Comment: I can't see any images to change to div's, I can only see `div` and `li` that have images in their background property. And both of them can have text with no changes at all. To remove the background images just delete the corresponding background-image property for each css rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. As was said by LGSon there are no `<img>` tags in your html, there are only `<div>` containers which background set to an image:

CSS

```
#itemOne {
  background-color: #ADFF2F;
  background-image: url("http://www.kirupa.com/images/blueSquare.png");
}
```

2. If you want to unset these images just remove `background-image` property
3. If you want to add some content into these containers then put it between `<div id="itemOne" class="content">` and `</div>`
4. If you want to get rid of black border that goes around these big colorful containers of yours you should remove the `border` property from `#contentContainer` or set it to `none`:

CSS

```
#contentContainer {
border: 5px black solid;
}
```

5. If you want to get rid of black color that goes around this border then remove `background-color: black;` from the `body`